# How can I prevent MySQL to become slow when using order by on a calculated column?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, stored-functions

I have a SELECT query which is using 6 Stored Functions. The Stored Functions are optimized and the query will run in 0.05 seconds when now ORDER BY is used. When I try to ORDER BY the query time drops to 15 seconds.

I tried to use temp tables and tables in memory, but creating these tables take still almost 15 seconds.

I tried to use a view, but then the SELECT with ORDER BY query is still slow.

**Example of the query:**

```
SELECT field1, fiedl2, field 3,  
    FUNC1(1, 2) AS score1,  
    FUNC2(1, 2) AS score2,  
    FUNC3(1, 2) AS score3,  
    FUNC4(1, 2) AS score4  
FROM table  
WHERE field1 = 1  
ORDER BY (score1 * 1 + score2 * 2 + score3 * 2 + score4 * 4) DESC;
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Harsh reality is that you're not going to be able to.  The problem is that MySQL is going to need to results of every FUNC() call for every row, ***then*** apply that (a*1 + b*2 + c*2 * d*4) to every row, ***then*** and only then will it be able to sort them.  To speed these up you're going to need to pre-calculate all the values when you insert them into the table, and then add an index to the final calculated column.  This way you're sorting at the time that you *write* the data instead of when you *read* the data.  It also means that you're sorting once per write, rather than once per read.

Comment: Thanks, I already was affraid someone would gonna say that! But just to make sure: Is there no way to somehow cache the results of the Stored Functions? I'm really hoping there is a clever solution to it. Because the pre-calculation of all the rows would take too much time.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with that; In what way do you consider `cache the results of the Stored Functions` to be any different from `pre-calculation of all the rows`?  Perhaps you can argue that a caching strategy is transient and the pre-calculation is persistent.  But in this you'd want the 'cache' to always be full, ergo persistent storage, ergo storing the results in your table.  Additionally, calculating the values only costs 0.05s, while sorting them costs 14.95s; which means that you need them pre-sorted (indexed), and that's impossible without them being pre-calculated.

Comment: We found some solution with caching, I will take the query to 3.5 seconds, instead of 15 seconds. So that's a big difference. So I trying to rethink the situation and look how much effort the pre-calculation will take. Thanks amigo!

Comment: That's very interesting!  Please could you include information on what you did to implement this caching?  Also, it seems (to me) to imply that it's made a fundamental difference to the execution plan (explain plan in MySQL?), as you yourself showed that it only takes 0.05s to calculate the values.  Have you had a look to compare the plans before and after the caching change?  I'm sure your finding would be extremely useful to people out there *(and very interesting to me personally)*.

Comment: Take a look to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0y9qnTgjbQg, it's a simple thing, but it works. Because the ORDER BY is refering to the Stored Functions a lot and the cache just makes it a fractions quicker per Stored Function. Fraction profit x a lot of referals is also a big profit.